# PHP - creating a 2-dimensional array

Tags: php

```
$city=array('delhi','noida','mumbai','noida');
$name=array('ankit','atul','ramu','manu');
```

I want to create a 2-dimensional array using the two arrays above, with the name of the cities as keys and the corresponding names as the values. The names must be sorted.

Comment: That would be an associative array, not a 2 dimensional array. I suggest you show some attempt to actually solve this yourself (or go to rent-a-coder or elancer for help).

Comment: @David I thought this was a Q&A site - is posting a question here not a valid attempt to get help? I thought that was the point.

Comment: There is "getting help" and there is "plz send teh codez"

Comment: The difference usually lies in the individual's experience level. I don't see anything wrong with this question for a budding developer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$arr = array_combine($city, $name);
asort($arr);
```

[`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) creates an array using the array values of the first argument as key and the values of the second array as values. And [`asort`](http://php.net/asort) sorts the array values while maintaining the association of key and value.

Comment: Dammit Gumbo, you're just too fast for me! +1

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called array_combine($array1, $array2) which make your 2 arrays combine as Key(as array1) and Value(as array2).

`$Mixedarray = array_combine($array1, $array2);`